# Can i declare an Object properties must contain a or b?

Tags: typescript

when i declare an Object like this:
`interface obj {
 a?:string,
 b?string
}`

but i want the attribute a not to exist, the attribute b must exist.
`let obj:obj={}`  It is allowed ,i want it is not allowed
`let obj:obj={a:'a'}` or `let obj:obj={b:'b'}`  if i want It is allowed. what should I do?

Comment: `type Obj = { a: string, b?: string } | { a?: string, b: string }` but I assume you want something less verbose

Comment: I guess type obj = { a: string } | { b: string }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "or" operator `|` when declaring your type

```
type obj = { a: string } | { b: string }
```

If you want to add more properties to this type, you can use "union type" (`&`)

```
type extendedObj = obj & { c: string }
```

This type will accept both

```
{ a: string, c: string }
```

And

```
{ b: string, c: string }
```

But not

```
{ a: string, b: string, c: string }
```